# jQuery star rating system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a very simple system

1. Hover and add class "hover".
2. Click event removes class "hover" and adds class "rated"
3. When you exit and reenter mouseout remove class "rated".
4. If there were no changes in and not remove class "rated"

My intention is to finish this system, my knowledge is very limited in javascript.

```
mouseover: function(){
  // remove hover
  t.rate.eventDrain();
  // fill hover
  t.rate.eventFill($(this));
},
mouseout: function(){
  t.rate.eventDrain();
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unm5N/7/

**My Question:**
How to make so that you can edit the score whenever you want, but if there was no change in the mouseover leave the previous score.

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: What's you question?  The code works fine in the jsfiddle you provided.

Comment: Please reduce your fiddle to just what your question involves, and hit the TidyUp button before you update it.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm try create some one this [Example](http://www.cuevana.tv/#!/peliculas/5290/the-worlds-end) my problem is when rated if mouseover this class not remove.

Comment: @LorDex How to make so that you can edit the score whenever you want, but if there was no change in the mouseover leave the previous score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save selection state with `data-selected` attribute used on clicked star. This will allow you to return to **pre-mouseover** selection state on `mouseout` event

So, here is the code:

## HTML:

```
<div id="rating">
    <a class="star"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
    <a class="star"></a>
    <!-- as many as you need -->

        <input id="getRating" type="button" value="Rate!"></input>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
a.star {
    display:block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url(http://sc.cuevana.tv/new/img/rate_list.png);
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.star.hover {
    background-position: 0 -20px;
}

a.star.rated {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
```

## JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".star", function (e) {
    //clearing currrently "rated" star
    $(".star").removeAttr("data-selected");

    var $this = $(this);
    //un-"rating" all the following stars
    $this.nextAll(".star").removeClass("rated");

    //mark clicked star with data-selected attribute
    $this.addClass("rated").attr("data-selected", "true");

    //mark previous stars
    $this.prevAll(".star").addClass("rated");
});

$(document).on("mouseover", ".star", function (e) {
    //unmark rated stars
    $(".star").removeClass("rated");
    var $this = $(this);

    //mark currently hovered star as "hover"
    $(this).addClass("hover");

    //mark preceding stars as "hover"
    $this.prevAll(".star").addClass("hover");
});

$(document).on("mouseout", ".star", function (e) {
    //un-"hover" all the stars
    $(".star").removeClass("hover");

    //mark star with data-selected="true" and preceding stars as "rated"
    $("[data-selected='true']").addClass("rated").prevAll(".star").addClass("rated");
});

$(document).on("click", "#getRating", function (e) {
    //wise comment here
    var rating = $(".star.rated").length;
    alert(rating);
});
```

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/mXqG2/3/).

Comment: I'm sorry, but being new I can not add reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to "re-vote" if needed.

You are going to need to add a few if statements, but this should do the trick.  It's messy, but I was in a hurry.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unm5N/8/)**

```
 mouseover: function(){
        if(!t.rate){
          t.rate.eventDrain();
        }else{
          t.rate.eventFill($(this));
        }`
```

*Please note that the below is the incomplete function - just provided for example:*

```
 click: function(){
        if($(this).prevAll().attr("class") == 'rated hover')
        {
            $("div.puntuar a").removeClass('rated');
            $(this).add($(this).prevAll()).addClass('rated');
        }else{
            $(this).add($(this).prevAll()).addClass('rated');
        }
```

Comment: Exactly that's what I'm trying to do, just check your code, there is a problem,if you have already voted and vote again, the "rated" class must be removed "temporarily",because if you enter "mouseover" and not make any changes to display the previous vote